# How to check which html file the user is currently on?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to check if the user is in the index.html and I have this code down.

```
console.log(window.location.pathname)

if ( window.location.pathname === '/' ){
   //code for index page
   console.log("In index")
}else{
   console.log("Not in index")
}
```

Now it always returns as `false` even though I am completely in the index.html file.

This is the logs that I get from chrome.

```
/C:/Users/krist/Documents/tuts/firebase-functions/public/index.html
```

It works when I type that whole path in but Im just worried that it's too long and if the path changes it messes up the code. How do I go on about this?

Comment: If I were you, I'd put the code on a server instead of a local file, then it'll be a lot more predictable - path changes won't be an issue anymore

Comment: Hey do you mean like a firebase server? Sorry Im completely new with web development.

Comment: Any server whose hosted stuff is accessible from a web browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to fetch the URL from the browser, you should just put something like

```
<script>
const isIndexPage = true;
</script>
```

in `index.html`, and then check that value when you need to know whether you're on that page.  Alternatively, you could have an element on the page you check for, say an empty `<div>` with a particular `id`.

However, if you still want to do what you're trying to do, you should try something like the `String.prototype.endsWith`, e.g.

```
   window.location.pathname.endsWith('index.html')
|| window.location.pathname.endsWith('/')
```

Depending on how your site is laid out you may have to check more than this, e.g. if there are various subdirectories and you want to know you're not in one of those.  This is part of why I don't recommend it.